# Font Awesome with Metro UI CSS

Tags: c#, metro-ui-css

I am using Metro UI project with my layout. I also added the font `awesome` into my project but when I use the `metro` and font `awesome` together, there have some issues:

```
<div class="tile-content icon">
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-ticket fa-fw"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to set the `fa` icon into Metro UI title but when I run the code, I cannot see the icon from the title:

[image]

If i only add following:

```
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-fw"></i>
```

Everything is fine... Somebody that can help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to "force" the font-awesome font:

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

This block is in the `font-awesome.css` file and you need to add the `!important` so Metro UI does not override it.
If you do not want/can edit the original CSS file you should also be able to fix this by adding the following to your own CSS file:

```
.fa {
  font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}
```

The reason for this problme is, that one style from Metro UI CSS does override the `font-family` style for the tiles and so the font-awesome font is not used anymore by default.